# How to localize name of iOS application

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, localization

I was trying to localize my iOS App. And can't do this.

0. In info.plist I have:

   ```
   Bundle Name = $(PRODUCT_NAME)
   Bundle Display Name = $(PRODUCT_NAME)
   ```
1. Created a infoPlist.strings file
2. Localized this file.
3. In each localized file I wrote:

   ```
   "CFBundleDisplayName" = "My_App_Name";
   "CFBundleName" = "My_App_Name";
   ```
4. Added a Bool to info.plist named "Application has localized display name" and changed it to YES.

I have changed the iPhone language for infoPlist.strings localizations, but this doesn't take effect. App name doesn't change from the name, that I wrote at the project creating.

Comment: Did you delete the app before trying the new localization? I think the localized name will only be applied during install.

Comment: I check (before and after you say) with App deletion from iPhone and simulator. It's not a reason...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The reason for bundle name doesn't localize was that I name localize file "infoPlist.strings". It should be "InfoPlist.strings" (I in upper case like in Info.plist).

Answer (score 3):

[image]

In my case I had to localize `(English, deprecated)`.
`InfoPlist.strings(Base)` was.. not used.

Adding `"CFBundleName" = "My_App_Name";` in `InfoPlist.string` is enough.

Comment: Also check that your `InfoPlist.strings` is marked as Target Membership of your Target.