# Is Internationalize Flutter app name possible?

Tags: android, flutter

New to flutter, is there a way to internationalize my app name. I see this is possible with other apps.

I was able to get strings within the app internationalized following the guide here: https://phrase.com/blog/posts/flutter-localization/

However, I think app name is stored in `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` so that is not something I can change with the flutter internationalization packages.

Is this possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Flutter,

Yes you can localize (Internationalize) the Flutter App Name,

- For **Android**: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56754432/11217945)
- For **IOS**: Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27848532/11217945) and the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27972906/11217945) on it.

Comment: Wow, thanks, that is exactly what I need. I was doing intertionalization within Flutter so my searches involved flutter (I googled "flutter internationalization app name") and didn't find anything. Now I realize this is purely an Android issue and had to be searched and solved along android lines. Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes it is a Native Problem, You're welcome ❤